# Error while deploying smart contract on mainnet of ethereum

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, error, gas-estimate, mainnet

when I deploy a smart contract on Goerli testnet then it will easily be deployed but when I try to deploy the same contract on mainnet then it gives me this particular error even I have ethers in my account I face this issue latest version of remix ide.

**Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"insufficient funds for transfer","id":6390118762518004}**

Comment: Can you share the contract code? Possible causes of the error, not enough funds, revert error caused in the constructor, wrong seed/private key, incorrect network.

Comment: it gives me error for the deployment of any contract even for the simple one

Comment: Do you have enough funds? Are you selecting the correct wallet to pay the funds?

Comment: Basically, the problem is if I don't have funds in mainnet metamask should pop up in order to calculate the required gas fee.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy your contract on mainnet, you'll need to increase the amount of ETH in your account to cover the deployment cost, which is determined by the gas price and the complexity of the contract.

Comment: Yeah i have balance in my account but still gives me this particular error i don't know why atleast metamask should popup